# Find the dimension of $W=W_{1}\cap W_{2}\cap W_{3}.$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let  $W_{1},W_{2}$ and $W_{3}$ be three **distinct** subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{10}$ such that each of $W_{i}$ has dimension $9.$ If $W=W_{1}\cap W_{2}\cap W_{3}$ find $\dim W$.

**Attempt**: I think $W$ can have dimension either $8$ or $7$.

Since, in a vector space $V$, for any subspaces $A$ and $B:$

> $\max\{0,\dim A+\dim B-\dim (A+B)\} ~\le~\dim (A \bigcap B) ~\le ~\min(\dim B,\dim A)\}$
>
> where $\dim (A+B) \le \dim V $.

Using the above and $\dim (W_1 \bigcap W_2) \le 10$, we obtain:

$\max\{0,18-\dim (W_1+W_2)\} ~\le~\dim (W_1 \bigcap W_2) ~\le ~\min(\dim W_1,\dim W_2)\}$

$\implies \max\{0,18-10\} ~\le~\dim (W_1 \bigcap W_2) ~\le ~\min(9,9)\}$

$\implies \dim (W_1 \bigcap W_2)=8$ ( as $W_1,W_2$ are distinct)

Applying the inequality again, we get:

$\max\{0,\dim W_3+\dim (W_1 \bigcap W_2)-\dim (W_3+(W_1 \bigcap W_2))\} ~\le~\dim (W_3 \bigcap W_1 \bigcap W_2) ~\le ~\min(\dim W_3,\dim W_1 \bigcap W_2)\}$

where $\dim (W_3+(W_1 \bigcap W_2)) \le 10$

$\implies \max\{0,9+8-10\} ~\le~\dim (W_3 \bigcap W_1 \bigcap W_2) ~\le ~\min(9,8)\}$

$\implies 7 \le \dim (W_3 \bigcap W_1 \bigcap W_2) \le 8$

Thus, $\dim (W_3 \bigcap W_1 \bigcap W_2)$ can take the value either $7$ or $8$. If $\dim (W_3 \bigcap W_1 \bigcap W_2)=8 \implies W_1 \bigcap W_2 \subset W_3$

> Did I attempt this correctly? Is there a way to further rule out one of these dimensions?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are entirely correct so far, in showing that
$$7 \le \dim (W_1 \bigcap W_2 \bigcap W_3) \le 8.$$
Now to prove that both dimensions do indeed occur, you should give examples of triples of subspaces $W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_3$ such that
$$\dim (W_1 \bigcap W_2 \bigcap W_3)=7,8.$$

Comment: Let the basis for the triple intersection be the first $8$ elements of standard basis of $\mathbb R^{10}$. Then this can be extended to form a basis each for $W_1,W_2,W_3$. But, since $W_i$'s are distinct, doing so will give a basis of length $11$ for $\mathbb R^{10}$ which is impossible. Am I correct?

Comment: Could you give me some hints for examples of dimension 8 and 7

Comment: @MathMan No; the three extending vectors for $W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_3$ need not be linearly independent from eachother. I guess that's a hint too.